# While trying to pass a method of a templated class to another class using pointer to functions,get Error C3867 use '&' to create a pointer to a member

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
class B;
template <typename T>
class A
{
    B b;
public:
    T func(T num) {
        return num + 10;
    }
    void setter() {
        b.attSet(func);
    }
    void display() {
        b.run();
    }
};

class B
{
    int (*m_funcptr)(int) {};
public:
    void attSet(int (*funcptr)(int)) {
        m_funcptr = funcptr;
    }
    void run() {
        std::cout << m_funcptr(2);
    }
};

int main() {
    A<int> a;
    a.setter();
    a.display();
}
```

So, I essentially have a templated class which makes a callback function for another class (non template). when passing the member function of the templated class to the actual class it generates Error C3867 use '&' to create a pointer to a member. I read all the stuff on Microsoft website and also here, tried all the possible solutions and still no answer. any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Member functions (methods) need to be passed differently at least partly because of `this`.

Comment: [Here's some good reading on the topic](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members)

Comment: you cannot forward declare `A` when `B` has a member of type `A`. Please make sure to post a [mcve] and include the complete error message

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you. (https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members) was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after reading a bunch of articles I fixed the problem by making

```
T func(T num) {
    return num + 10;
}
```

,whose address is going to be passed to another class' pointer to function
member variable, a class member function (static).
like this:

```
static T func(T num) {
    return num + 10;
 }
```